# Emacs incompatible with oh-my-zsh?

Tags: ansi-term, multi-term, zsh

I'm noticing something really odd in my `ansi-term` windows on my new Mac, see below:

[image]

I am using:

```
GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6 (Build 16G1036)) of 2017-11-10
```

which I installed using `brew` using:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD  --with-cocoa --with-ctags --with-dbus --with-gnutls  --with-imagemagick@6 --with-mailutils --with-modules
```

Note that:

- I see this problem even with `emacs -Q`.
- I also get this problem when using  https://emacsformacosx.com/

#### oh-my-zsh and termsupport.sh

I only seem to have this problem when I load **oh-my-zsh**. As I mentioned in [a ticket I opened with them](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/6411), the problem seems to be [termsupport.sh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh) specifically. The problem only happens if oh-my-zsh loads that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. As I mentioned in [the ticket](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/6411), I was setting the variable `EMACS` myself in `.zshenv` to help setup `PATH`.
 As it happens [`termsupport.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh) [also uses this variable name](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh#L13) internally. All I had to do is rename my own variable to something else, and it all now works.